# Why can't the underscore be matched by '\W'?

Tags: python, regex

I know that `_` cannot be matched by `\W` while any other punctuation can.
As the docs state: `\w` is a set of alphanumeric characters **and** the **underscore**.

At the same time:

[image]

I have always been confused by this but never actually bothered to question why.

Does it have to do with the special role that `_` plays in Python?

Comment: `_` does not have any special role in Python outside of the REPL, so I doubt this is the reason.

Comment: perl regexp acts in the same way so I doubt it is a special thing in Python

Comment: Yep, this isn't unique to Python - see e.g. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ae5bf541(v=vs.90).aspx for the .NET syntax, for example.

Comment: There's no really satisfactory answer [for perl](http://www.perlmonks.org/bare/?node_id=347189), either, it seems. Probably `\w` was interpreted as *language word* aka identifier. The underscore makes sense, then. The reference to sed having a similar function seems bogus, because sed has POSIX re or ere, which have no notion of `\w`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lots of Python's regular expression syntax in the module `re` comes from Perl, which was [influenced by `sed` and `awk`](http://www.perlmonks.org/bare/?node_id=347189). The `\w` comes from there and has a long history.

---

In the original `regex` module (which was deprecated in Python 1.5), `\w` did **not** include `_`, as is evident from [Python 1.4 documentation](https://docs.python.org/release/1.4/lib/node51.html#SECTION00521000000000000000):

> **`\w`**
>
> Matches any alphanumeric character; this is equivalent to the set `[a-zA-Z0-9]`.

---

P.S. While it is not very convenient can match all non-`\w` + `_` with a character class `[\W_]`.

Comment: Inconvenient, yes. I also think this is just inconsistent and generates confusion.

Comment: One fun fact: `%w` in Lua patterns does not match `_`, it only matches alphanumeric symbols.

Comment: It didn't have to be compatible with sed/awk obviously